# QTimer::singleShot not work in the qkeyevent

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtimer

I create a keyevent which if I push key "A" it will do the function `A()`.

In the A() function, I increment  global parameter "g" by 1 and create a `QTimer::singleShot` to wait 2 seconds and print the value of "g". For example, the initial value of "g" is 0. When I push Key "A" twice, the output value of "g" should be 1 in the first time and 2 in the second time.

However, when I push the key in 2 seconds, I found that the `QTimer::singleShot` not work in the first time and the output is **"first:g=2,second:g=2"**. Why the output is **"first:g=2,second:g=2"** not **"first:g=1,second:g=2"**? Also why the  `QTimer::singleShot` not work in the first time,it just print the values in the same time, did not wait 2s.

```
int g = 0;
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
  Qt::Key_A: 
    g++;
    qtimer1->singleShot(2000, this, SLOT(a()));
}

//slots
a() {
  qdebug << g;//print value
}
```

If I push the key in 2s,the output are "2, 2" not "1,2". It means that `QTimer::singleShot` not work. How can i do to get the true values when i push the key so quickly.

Comment: As the output is `2, 2`, If you only print the g letter.

Comment: Understand that you are increasing the number in the keyPressevent, that causes that behavior that is normal, for example if you press 2 times the variable g will increase 2 times and just the slot prints the value of the variable, if you press twice the key A before printing the variable you will only see that 2 is printed and then 2, if you want to print 1 and then 2, you have to make the increment in the slot.

Comment: That's why i use the QTimer::singleShot . I try to stop the process for two seconds, that will have enough time to print, but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a()` slot simply outputs the current value of `g` at the time the slot runs. If you press two keys before the first one-shot is actually *fired,* that will cause `g` to have been incremented *twice* by the key release event function *before* the first output has happened.

In fact, if you go whole hog and press a key a hundred times within that initial two seconds, what you will see is a whole lot of `100` values output.

*One* possible approach may be to defer the updating of `g` until the last possible moment, such as with:

```cpp
int g = 0;
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    qtimer1->singleShot(2000, this, SLOT(a()));
}
a() {
  qdebug << (++g);
}
```

although this won't work if there's some *other* piece of code somewhere that relies on `g` being updated at the original point.

Unfortunately, `singleShot` generates a `timeout` event that carries no additional information. If you *need* extra information (such as the value of `g` at the time it was modified), you can create your *own* thread in the key release event, give it the current value to be stored as a member, then start the thread - it will then sleep for as long as necessary and print its *stored* value rather than the current `g`.

---

Here's some example code that shows this in action. The `MyTask` represents your key release event function in that it starts an individual thread to manage the timing and data to print. Each time it gets an "event" (which is generated by a simple loop in this case but, in yours, it will be in response to a key being released), it kicks off a thread, passing it the current value of `g`. The thread object stores that `g` for later use.

And, once the thread has waited a suitable time, it prints out that stored value of `g`, regardless of what the main task has done to the real `g` in the meantime.

```cpp
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread(int useGVal): m_gVal(useGVal) {}
public slots:
    void run()
    {
        QThread::msleep(6000);
        std::cout << QTime::currentTime().toString().toStdString()
            << " MyThread, g is " << m_gVal << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_gVal;
};

class MyTask : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTask(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
public slots:
    void run()
    {
        MyThread *x[5];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << QTime::currentTime().toString().toStdString()
                << " MyTask, g <- " << ++g << std::endl;
            x[i] = new MyThread(g);
            x[i]->start();
            QThread::msleep(1000);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            x[i]->wait();
            std::cout << QTime::currentTime().toString().toStdString()
                << " MyTask, thread #" << (i + 1) << " finished"
                << std::endl;
        }
        emit finished();
    }
signals:
    void finished();
private:
    int g = 0;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication appl(argc, argv);
    MyTask *task = new MyTask(&appl);
    QObject::connect(task, SIGNAL(finished()), &appl, SLOT(quit()));
    QTimer::singleShot(0, task, SLOT(run()));

    return appl.exec();
}
```

Running this code shows you what happens. Even though the main thread is updating `g` many times before the worker threads start using it, the value used in the worker threads is what you expect (the value that existed when the worker thread was created):

```
10:49:48 MyTask, g <- 1
10:49:49 MyTask, g <- 2
10:49:50 MyTask, g <- 3
10:49:51 MyTask, g <- 4
10:49:52 MyTask, g <- 5

10:49:54 MyThread, g is 1
10:49:54 MyTask, thread #1 finished

10:49:55 MyThread, g is 2
10:49:55 MyTask, thread #2 finished

10:49:56 MyThread, g is 3
10:49:56 MyTask, thread #3 finished

10:49:57 MyThread, g is 4
10:49:57 MyTask, thread #4 finished

10:49:58 MyThread, g is 5
10:49:58 MyTask, thread #5 finished
```

Comment: Thanks.How can i do to make sure that the keyevent will be executed after 2s while i push the key in 1s.

Comment: @MotoJack, the key release event will be executed when you release the key - that is its purpose. The answer shows how to defer the update of `g` until it's needed (based on the code given). It also gives you a method to use if you want `g` updated *immediately* on key release but still want the value reported as of that time rather than when the slot is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.In my case, the source codes are more complex and can not be solved by using qdebug << (++g). I try to use thread to solve it and now i don't know how to put keyReleaseEvent in a thread.Also should i use qmutex and eventloop.exce() etc. in the thread. It's my first my time to use Thread, can you show more idea?

Comment: @MotoJack, you don't put the key releaase event in a thread, you *start* a thread in the key release event and give it enough information to carry out its task. Hang on a minute, I'll dodgy something up for you ...

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. you mean i just put a thread in  key release event and put "g++; qtimer1->singleShot(2000, this, SLOT(a()));" in the thread?

Comment: @MotoJack, I've added some proof-of-concept code which you should have a look at.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried and i found a problem. which i want to get the g every 6s in your code,like " 10:50:00 MyThread, g is 2" not "10:49:55".In my case, the process will last for 2s one keypush and update the value.

Comment: The "keypress" event should update `g` then create a thread to wait some time before printing/using that value (rather than a value that may have been updated in later keypress events). That's why it sleeps then does the job once. As far as I can tell, that solves the issue you raised in the question, which was why the value appeared to be `2` rather than `1` when you had more keypresses before the one-shot fired. It sounds like you have a different question based on your second-to-most-recent comment. If so, that should be asked as a different question.

Comment: Thanks,that may be a different question. But i don't understand  QThread::msleep(6000); just work one time in your code, and std::cout work 5times

Comment: @Moto, there are *five* key-release events emulated in `MyTask` - the loop running `i` from `0` to `4` inclusive will emulate these events one second apart. Each event will result in a single thread being spawned off to capture the current `g` and print it out six seconds later. The same would be true when you do a similar operation from within your *real* key-release event procedure - every single release will queue a new thread which will store the current `g`, wait six seconds (or whatever you configure) and then print that `g` and exit.

Comment: You mean that five key-release events emulated in MyTask and almost execute QThread::msleep(6000) in the same time, so i just look like have  worked one time?

Comment: **Everyone, you do understand that this answer is a joke, right?** Yes, I mean it: this answer is a joke. How come nobody figured it out? Pax: you devil incarnate :) This is a good one. I'm upvoting just for comedic value. **Do not use this code for anything but entertainment. You've been warned. I'm serious. STOP now until you understand why this is indeed a joke.** It has at least one upvote (from me) just because it's funny as heck.

Comment: not answer. singleshoot not work

Comment: Not sure why Kuba thinks this is a joke, it shows how to "disconnect" the value of `g` from effects on it in the main thread. That way, the value it possessed when the thread was *created* is the important one. As to Mr Tu's rather terse comment that it doesn't work, I would posit that they're doing something wrong. As per the output when you run the code, it works exactly as described.

Answer (score -1):

Threading jokes aside, you can capture the current value of `g` in a lambda and submit the lambda for execution by the timer. If you're stuck with Qt 4 or a pre-C++11 compiler, you can explicitly queue the values to be submitted to the method.

This is a complete example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/timer-lambda-notadevil-45910623
#include <QtWidgets>

class LogWindow : public QPlainTextEdit {
   Q_OBJECT
   int g = {};
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
   // C++98
   QQueue<int> logQueue;
#endif
   void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * event) override {
      if (event->key() == Qt::Key_A) {
         g++;
#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
         // C++14
         QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [this, val=g]{ log(val); });
#elif __cplusplus >= 201103L
         // C++11
         int val = g;
         QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [=]{ log(val); });
#else
         // C++98
         logQueue.enqueue(g);
         QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, SLOT(log()));
#endif
      }
      QPlainTextEdit::keyReleaseEvent(event);
   }
   void log(int value) {
      appendPlainText(QString::number(value));
   }
   Q_SLOT void log() { // becasue MOC doesn't define __cplusplus :(
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
      // C++98
      log(logQueue.dequeue());
#endif
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   LogWindow w;
   w.appendPlainText("Press and release 'a' a few times.\n");
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

If you're still confused as to why the threading joke was a joke: it makes fun of the "if unsure, throw a thread at it" approach espoused by the not-knowing-any-better circles of the public.